# How can I improve the performance of a Seda queue?

Tags: apache-camel

Take this example:

```
from("seda:data").log("data added to queue")
                  .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
                  .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                  .process(new Processor() {
                      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                              exchange.setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, "UTF-8");
                      }
                   })
                  .recipientList(header(RECIPIENT_LIST))
                  .ignoreInvalidEndpoints().parallelProcessing();
```

Assume the RECIPENT_LIST header contains only one http endpoint. For a given http endpoint, messages should be processed in order, but two messages for different end points can be processed in parallel.

Basically, I want to know if there is anything be done to improve performance. For example, would using concurrentConsumers help?

Comment: Hi yalis, have you solved the issue?  I have similar issue even with concurrentConsumers or threads(...)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189210/camel-k-seda-component-get-out-of-memory-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SEDA with concurrentConsumers > 1 would absolutely help with throughput because it would allow multiple threads to run in parallel...but you'll need to implement your own locking mechanism to make sure only a single thread is hitting a given http endpoint at a given time

otherwise, here is an overview of your options: http://camel.apache.org/parallel-processing-and-ordering.html

in short, if you can use JMS, then consider using [ActiveMQ message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) as its trivial to use and is designed for exactly this use case (parallel processing, but single threaded by groups of messages, etc).