# Camel K SEDA component throws out of memory error

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I have gotten an OutOfMemoryError in my Camel K route. I am using [SEDA](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/seda-component.html)(one producer and multiple consumers) and feeding events with 10,000 events per second, even I use multiple consumers the error was thrown, does anyone know how to improve the performance?

I have tried to increase the consumers numbers but the issue hasn't been resolved and I tried increase the memory but the in-memory queue take too much memory.

Error Message:

```
2021-12-01 17:42:58,401 syslog-basic-68d776c9b4-js4cd io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint[1] WARN  [io.net.cha.AbstractChannelHandlerContext] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - NettyConsumerExecutorGroup) An exception 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Here's my source code for the SEDA routes:

```
  from("netty:udp://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "?sync=false&receiveBufferSize=16777216")
  // .log("in: ${body}")
  .to("seda:next?size=5000&timeout=0&blockWhenFull=true");


  from("seda:next?concurrentConsumers=5")
  .unmarshal(myDataFormat)
  .routePolicy(myPolicy)
  .process(myProcessor)
  .choice()
  .when(body().contains(MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS)).to("log:warning").otherwise()
  .log("log:${body}");
```

[image]

Comment: Why not run multiple instances of the pod? Scale the deployment would be easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Currently just working on tweaking one pod, haven't tried scale out yet.

Comment: Looks like you are using UDP but the only hassle you might have is duplicate msg being picked up. Using a idempotent consumer would handle that for you.

Comment: @HaifengZhang did you find solution for this problem. ? Even i am facing same problem

Comment: @mahi244 Unfortunately no. The Camel K project was abandoned . Camel K isn't ready for production imo since the documentation is too limited. Our project met too many issues and they were not able to be solved until we get answers from the official Camel K team.